# How to change the value of simulink block during the simulation?

Tags: simulink, stateflow

i have a constant block in a simulink model; i would like to change its value during the simulation when a particular event occurred in a stateflow chart. how can i do it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the Stateflow chart output indicates when this event has occurred, or if you can add an additional output that toggles when the event occurs, loop this indicator back (possibly through a *Unit Delay* block) to the control input of *Switch* block. The two inputs to the *Switch* would be two *Constant* blocks containing the two different values.

If you must do this [programmatically](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/programmatic.html) without modifying the model, take a look at the reference for the [`sim`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/sim.html) command. I should warn you that this may not be trivial to accomplish.

Also, if want to be able to modify the contents of a *Constant* block mid-simulation (i.e. make it *tunable*), you may have to turn off Simulink's optimization settings that inline invariant parameters.

Comment: i try to use the command set_param but the simulation was interrupted. there'is an other way to change the value in the constant block?

Comment: @Deviltrigger You might have to pause the simulation before using `set_param` to change the value.

Answer (score 0):

You can also add a [Slider Gain](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/simulink/slref/slidergain.html) block between your constant block and the Stateflow block. This would allow you to change the value of the slider gain block during simulation, without the need to change the value of the constant block.